# How to write formatted string in text file

Tags: c#, .net, string, text, stringbuilder

I am using `StringBuilder` to format my string values like below

> Student Number: 3602
>
> Registered On: 9/11/2018 12:00:00 AM
>
> Enrollment number:  0

but when I am writing this to a text file using below code

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"LocaltempPath\Sheet.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

my entire formatting is getting missed, instead of above shown format, values gets copied in one line of text file! How to preserve format while writing to text file?

Update : My StringBuilder code

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Student Number: " + StId);
 sb.Append("\n");
 sb.Append("Registered On: " + regdate);
 sb.Append("\n");
 sb.Append("Enrollment No: " + regnumber);
 sb.Append("\n");
```

Comment: Show the code that puts data in the stringbuilder

Comment: Are you sure it is one line? When you use only line feed *(`\n`)* as line separator and open the file in Windows Notepad, it will be in single line. But when you use a good editor, that support Linux line endings, the file will be displayed correctly. The second option is, that the string in `sb` is really created without new lines

Comment: `File.WriteAllText(@"LocaltempPath\Sheet.txt", sb.ToString());` check if `sb` has *new lines* (`\n`). `Console.Write(sb.ToString());` - can you see the format or it's one line?

Comment: @CaiusJard Please see update code..thanks

Comment: `sb.AppendLine();` instead of `sb.Append("\n");`: some programs (like NotePad) don't like `\n` but want Windows `\r\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, don't use hardcoded "\n" to mean newline, unless you're preparing data for a unix system

Do this instead:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Student Number: " + StId);
sb.AppendLine();
sb.AppendLine("Registered On: " + regdate);
sb.AppendLine("Enrollment No: " + regnumber);
```

AppendLine() can be used without any arguments to just put a newline in, and I do this above to put a new line on the end of the string that you created the stringbuilder with. Could also have done this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Student Number: " + StId);
sb.AppendLine("Registered On: " + regdate);
sb.AppendLine("Enrollment No: " + regnumber);
```

If you want more control over the format of the dates etc:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Student Number: " + StId);
sb.AppendFormat("Registered On: {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}\r\n", regdate);
sb.AppendLine("Enrollment No: " + regnumber);
```

Finally, every call to AppendXXX() on a stringbuilder returns the same stringbuilder, so you can call like this and save some typing:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Student Number: ").AppendLine(StId)
  .Append("Registered On: ").AppendLine(regdate);
  .Append("Enrollment No: ").AppendLine(regnumber);
```

Really, you should avoid mixing string concatenation with + and stringbuilder - it's more efficient if you're doing a lot of stringbuilding to just use the stringbuilder. It might not make your code more readable though

In terms of readable code, you might also like to know that you can do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine($"Student Number: {StId}");
sb.AppendLine($"Registered On: {regdate}");
sb.AppendLine($"Enrollment No: {regnumber}");
```

In this trivial example it doesnt help much, but it can really help with strings that concatenate a lot of stuff:

```
$"Student Number: {StId}, Registered On: {regdate}, Enrollment No: {regnumber}"
//instead of
"Student Number: " + StId + ", Registered On: " + regdate + ", Enrollment No: " + regnumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sb.AppendLine instead of sb.Append to add text to separate lines.
Also if you are writing to file and need next line, use Environment.NewLine instead of \n.

Answer (score 0):

Different OSes (Unix, Windows, Mac) use different new-line characters ([Why?](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/YoureJustAnotherCarriageReturnLineFeedInTheWall.aspx)).

You're using `\n` explicitly, which is Linux default, but it's handling on Windows will depend on the editor you use to view the file (notepad will show all text as one long line). To use system default character for new lines, either use `sb.AppendLine()`, or `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n`.